# XPath for all elements with any attribute with specific value?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium to identify any HTML element that may have a specified value in any of its attributes. I was hoping that there would be some way in XPath to do this, but I haven't been able to find any answers yet.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, you have to transform HTML into xhtml if you want to apply xpath selections on it.

The xpath for selecting an (x)html element having a specified value in one of its attributes is:

```
//*[@*="specified value"]
```

Answer (score 40):

### Here are XPath expressions for selecting...

- **All elements**:

  ```
   //*
  ```
- **All elements with an attribute, `a`:**

  ```
   //*[@a]
  ```
- **All elements with an attribute `a` equal to `v`:**

  ```
   //*[@a='v']
  ```
- **All elements with any attribute:**

  ```
   //*[@*]
  ```
- **All elements with any attribute equal to `v`:**

  ```
   //*[@*='v']
  ```

*Credit to [@Pierre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35928064/290085) for first posting* `//*[@*='v']`.

Answer (score 9):

`//*[@*[contains(.,'val')]]`
Will find any descendant node from the root with any attribute containing 'val' in its value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys!! I tried this on XPathFiddle and it seems to work:

**Sample HTML**:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div my-attr1='value1'>
        <a>  
            <span my-attr2='value2'> Some Link </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <span my-attr3='value1'> Some Text </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Sample XPath** :  `html//*[@*='value1']`

The XPath above, selects the `div` with `my-attr1` and the `span` with `my-attr3`.

Answer (score -2):

`//a[@href[contains(.,'mailto:')]]` 
This path will find all a tags with href attribute contains "mailto:" string